# PHP check number have no decimals than add two decimal number

Tags: php

Input:

```
(1) 2
(2) 2.3
```

PHP:

```
<?php if(is_int($ledger['Amount'])){$Amount = $ledger['Amount'].'.00';}else{$Amount = $ledger['Amount'];};?>
```

Output:

```
(1) 2.00
(2) 2.30
```

Anyone can please help me How can I get my expected output? Sorry for weak English and please help me for improving quality of this question.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It's described after "Output"

Comment: Why not just use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) and not worry about it being a whole number?

Answer (score 1):

Do not invent the wheel:

```
echo number_format(2, 2);    // 2.00
echo number_format(2.3, 2);  // 2.30
```

Comment: How come you close as duplicate and answer it too?

Comment: First I answer, then close as duplicate)